# Inserting data from Spark application to Elasticsearch leaves unassigned shards

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have a scala spark application that should store some data to Elasticsearch 2.3.3. I'm trying to insert some very simple data using the following code:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster(master)
.set("spark.cores_max",maxCores.toString)
.set("spark.executor.memory","4g")
.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.setAppName("testapp")
.set("es.index.auto.create","true")
.set("es.nodes", "127.0.0.1")
.set("es.port","9200")
.set("es.http.timeout","5m")
.set("es.scroll.size","50")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val r2 = Map("arrival" -> "LA", "SFO" -> "San Fran")
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq(r2))
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs")
```

After this code is executed it inserts data, but creates 5 unassigned shards and cluster transfers to Yellow state. I tried to check from Elasticsearch logs, but didn't find anything relevant that would help me to solve the problem. All I can conclude from the logs is that 4 shards are created and then the following error happens before fifth shard is created:

> [2016-07-24 20:11:09,369][DEBUG][cluster.service ] [Cottonmouth] cluster state update task [create-index [spark], cause [api]] failed
>   [spark] IndexAlreadyExistsException[already exists]
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validateIndexName(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:138)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validate(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:473)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.access$100(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:97)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:192)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [2016-07-24 20:11:09,372][DEBUG][cluster.service ] [Cottonmouth] processing [create-index [spark], cause [api]]: took 3ms no change in cluster_state
>   [2016-07-24 20:11:09,372][DEBUG][rest.suppressed ] /spark Params: {index=spark}
>   [spark] IndexAlreadyExistsException[already exists]
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validateIndexName(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:138)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validate(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:473)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.access$100(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:97)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:192)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [2016-07-24 20:11:09,410][DEBUG][index.engine ] [Cottonmouth] [spark][0] no translog ID present in the current generation - creating one

I was trying this with single node Elasticsearch cluster on localhost as well as on the Amazon EC2 instance. It's the same in both cases.
I'm using scala 2.11.6, spark 1.6.1 and elasticsearch 2.3.3

Any idea what might be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: By default elasticsearch assigns 5 shards per each index created and creates 1 set of replica shards. In your case as you have single node, ES is unable to assign replica shards that is why you are seeing 5 unassigned  shards. If you [reduce replica](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings) to 0 then your cluster state will go to `green`

Comment: You're right about that. I had index creation at the application startup with number of replicas set to 0. Unfortunately, I had a typo in index name, so it created different index than the one I was using from the spark. Your comment helped me to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: If you write your comment as answer, I would accept it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I'm glad that it helped you. It would be sophisticated if you write an answer with steps how did you resolved it with the help of my comment.